# XmlHttpRequest error "xmlhttprequest is not a function"

Tags: protractor

I am trying to create an object of `xmlhttprequest` to read my xml file. But I am getting an error stated with

> msg xmlhttprequest is not a function.

I have implemented something like ...

```
var XmlHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XmlHttpRequest;
ar xhr = new XmlHttpRequest();
```

I have also tried to pass it through module declaration but still it won't work like

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require('../node_modules/jasmine_reporters/ext/jasmine.js'), 
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Comment: I am a newbie in this, so any comment or suggestion will be appreciated. And thanks in advance..!!

Comment: If you didn't installed XHR globally you shall set the full path to this, for example: `var XMLHttpRequest = require('../../node_modules/xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;`

Answer (score 0):

You may not have installed the xmlhttprequest npm package.  From a terminal (command prompt) in your project root, type:
`npm install xmlhttprequest`

Comment: Thanks .. I'll make a try and let u know.